# R Stargazer report coefficients, confidence intervals and exact p-values

Tags: r, latex, confidence-interval, p-value, stargazer

I am running a Country Fixed Effects model further including a dummy variable. 
I am using the Stargazer package, but can not seem to figure out how to report both the confidence intervals and the exact p-values. If I run my model:

```
stargazer(dummy_CPP, title = "xx",align = TRUE, 
          no.space = TRUE, ci = TRUE, 
          report = ('vc*p'), single.row = TRUE)
```

Only the p-values are in my output. Furthermore, as I have 30+ variables, the whole table can not fit into 1 page, as the p-values are reported underneath the coefficients, even though I use single.row = TRUE.

Comment: It'll be easier to help if you provide a [mcve] with some toy data.

Answer (score 4):

From the `stargazer` documentation;

report = a character string containing only elements of "v", "c", "s","t", "p", "*" that determines whether, and in which order, variable names ("v"), coefficients ("c"), standard errors/confidence intervals ("s"), test statistics ("t") and p-values ("p") should be reported in regression tables.

So to report CI and p values include both the letters "s" and "p". I don't know how to get it all on one line though (the command `single.row` only applies to standard errors/CI but not p values I think).

```
stargazer(dummy_CPP, title = "xx",align = TRUE, 
          no.space = TRUE, ci = TRUE, 
          report = ('vcsp'), single.row = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

Not using stargazer but my huxtable package:

```
library(plm)
library(dplyr)
library(huxtable)
dfr <- tibble( id = rep(1:10, 10), x = rnorm(100), y = x + id/10 + rnorm(100), time = rep(1:10, each = 10))

dummy_CPP <- plm(y ~ x, dfr, index = c("id", "time"), effect = "twoways")

huxreg(dummy_CPP, error_pos = 'right', error_format = "({std.error}) [{conf.low} - {conf.high}]", ci_level = 0.95, statistics = "nobs")
──────────────────────────────────────────────────
                          (1)                     
         ─────────────────────────────────────────
  x          1.100 ***   (0.093) [0.917 - 1.282]  
         ─────────────────────────────────────────
  nobs     100                                    
──────────────────────────────────────────────────
  *** p < 0.001; ** p < 0.01; * p < 0.05.
```

You can include p values with `{p.value}` inside the `error_format` string, and you can manipulate the table with standard R subsetting, or by changing the `font_size`, to make it fit on the page or split over multiple pages.

Comment: Thank you dash2!
As the output is to be included in my bachelor thesis, the design of it is quite important. How could this nicely be inserted in Lyx? I was hoping for something like Stargazer that provides LaTex coding.

Comment: Just use `to_latex()` or `print_latex()`. Or autoprint it using `options(huxtable.print=print_latex)`